# Power series of $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-4}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I do not understand how I can find the power series **with center in x=0** of the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-4}$$

I tried without succes in the following way:
$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-4}=\frac{1}{2} \bigg[\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-4}+\frac{1}{x^2+x-4}\bigg]$$

Now, for $\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-4}$ I know that

$$\int \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-4} dx=\mathrm{lg} (x^2+x-4) \implies \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-4}=\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}} ((-1)^n \frac{(x^2+x-4)^{n+1}}{n+1})$$
The last one using the power series of logarithm.

And for $\frac{1}{x^2+x-4}$ I can complete the square and write
$$\frac{1}{x^2+x-4}=\frac{1}{(x-1/2)^2+15/4}=(4/15) \frac{1}{(\frac{x-1/2}{225/16})^2+1}=(4/15) \frac{1}{1-(-(\frac{x-1/2}{225/16})^2)}=(4/15) \sum_{n \geq 0} (-(\frac{x-1/2}{225/16})^2)^{n}$$

But in both cases I don't get a power series with center in $x=0$ (I'm not even sure that these two are really power series), so I'm wrong.

What is the proper way to write the power series of $f(x)$ with center in $x=0$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Just start rewriting $$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+x-4}=-\frac{1+x}{4-x-x^2}=-\frac 14 \frac {1+x}{1-\frac{x+x^2}4}$$ Now consider the development (by Taylor series) of $\frac 1{1-y}$ and then replace $y$ by $\frac{x+x^2}4$.

When done, multiply by $-\frac{1+x}4$ and you should get something like $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5 x}{16}-\frac{9 x^2}{64}-\frac{29
   x^3}{256}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which could have been obtained by division.

**Edit**

*Another way to approach the problem.*

From the very first terms obtained by division, you can set $$f(x)=-\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {a_i }{4^{i+1}}x^i$$ and write the problem as $$x+1=(x^2+x-4)f(x)\implies (1+x)+(x^2+x-4)\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {a_i }{4^{i+1}}x^i=0$$ Looking at $x^0$ and $x^1$, we immediately get $a_0=1$ and $a_1=5$. Now, for any $n\geq 2$, we have, just as  B. Goddard commented,$$a_n=a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}$$ Using the standard method for recurrence relations, we have $$a_n=c_1 \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n+c_2
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n$$ and applying the initial conditions $a_0=1$ and $a_1=5$ $$a_n=\frac{1}{34} \left(\left(17-9 \sqrt{17}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1-\sqrt{17}\right)\right)^n+\left(17+9 \sqrt{17}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right)\right)^n\right)$$ which are integer numbers which correspond to sequence $A006131$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: A recursion for those numerators is $f_n = f_{n-1}+4f_{n-2}$.  The Binet forms give a formula, of course, but there ought to be a non-radical expression(?)

Comment: @B.Goddard. Good catch ! this is sequence $A006131$ at $OEIS$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing that does not convince me is that both in your answer and in my question we replace a polynomial of 2nd degree in a Taylor series: in the case of your answer we set $y=(x+x^2)/4$ and then we look at the series of $1/(1-y)$. This does not lead to a power series of $x$ centered in $x=0$, which should be in the form $\sum a_n x^n$. Is this a problem that can in some way be solved after having found the series as you described?

Comment: @Gianolepo. This is composition of series. Be sure it works.

Comment: Thanks again! If I may, I still miss how to end up with the complete expression of the power series, because if I try to do what suggested I get to 
$$(x+1) \frac{1}{1-\frac{x+x^2}{4}}=(x+1) \sum_{n \geq 0}  (\frac{x+x^2}{4})^n= \sum_{n \geq 0}  (\frac{x+x^2}{4})^n+ x  \sum_{n \geq 0}  (\frac{x+x^2}{4})^n$$

I don't see what I can do from here to get to a form $\sum a_n x^n$.

Comment: Did you think about the binomial expansion ? Have also a look at the sequence in OEIS. This could give you ideas. Cheers.